# PHP hash sha256 not working fine on server

Tags: php, web-services, api, hash, sha256

I'm working on web services and an API requires a variable called $signature that is equal to:

```
// Signature is generated by SHA256 (Api-Key + Shared Secret + Timestamp (in seconds))

$signature = hash("sha256", $apiKey.$sharedSecret.time());
```

The rest of the code is as follows and it uses PECL 2.5.3:

```
$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;

$request->setRequestUrl('https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0/status');
$request->setRequestMethod('GET');
$request->setHeaders(array(
'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
'x-signature' => $signature,
'api-key' => '******************************',
'accept' => 'application/json'
));


$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();

echo $response->getBody();
```

The thing is, if I generate and `var_dump` the `$signature` value on my local server and then paste it like this:

```
'x-signature' => 'b67bfd70f9ba8564eddfde0aa02dffb8aa6e24f937886ae80f77efcee139e5e5',
```

And then run the script on the proyect server, it gives me a correct response, but if I just put:

`'x-signature' => $signature,`...

It gives me a "Not authorized error". I don't know what's going wrong, I have printed the time on the proyect server and the difference is like 10 numbers between each other, even if I put them equally, the problem persists.

The **PHP version** from my local server is **5.5.12** and the one from the proyect server is **5.4.16**.

So, it could be the time function, which I don't think it is, or that the hash function differs from PHP versions, but that would be strange.

Please help.

Comment: To debug this problem, `echo` all the parts (`$apiKey`, `$sharedSecret`, `time()`) on both your local server and the project server. See if everything matches. Try hashing a known value, check the differences in the output files. etc and tell us if the outcome if you still need help after that.

Comment: "the one from the proyect server is 5.4.16" — Upgrade the project server! PHP 5.4 is [beyond end of life](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)! It does not receive security fixes any more! (And doing so will probably solve your problem as a happy side effect).

Comment: @Jacco Ok I will hash a value that doesn't change each time and tell you what happened

Comment: @Quentin, the proyect server has different vhosts, each one contains a different proyect, the server has the option to change version to each domain, but PECL library was compiled into all the server, which is version 5.4.16, the proyect server stays as it is, unless I ask the owner to change it. And I don't know if PECL could install itself into certain vhost.

Comment: @Jacco Hello, I `echo` the values like you said, the `$apikey` and `$sharedsecret` are exactly the same on both servers, I hashed the word "hello" on both servers, and the output was the same on both, the only value that was different on both was the value of the function `time()`. If I print the value on my local server and then quickly in one second I print the other one, the last 3 digits of the number are different, even if I sum the seconds that the server is missing the last 3 or 4 digits are always different, what can I do?

Comment: try using `$time = time();` on your local server; use the `$time` on your production server and see if both hashes are the same if you use the same value for `$time` with both.

Comment: @Jacco I resolved it by changing the time zone on server and correcting the time on there. Can I ask you another question related with the http\Client class or do I need to open another thread?

Comment: please open another question for any additional questions you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by changing the time zone on server and correcting the time on there.